# Apollonius circles

Tags: calculus

I have a question about apollonius circles:

If I have 3 points $A(a_{x},a_{y}), B(b_{x},b_{y}), C(c_{x},c_{y})$, and 2 ratios $r_{AB}$, and $r_{AC}$.

We draw the apollonius circles for the segment $AB$ with the ratio $r_{AB}$, and for the segment $AC$ with the segment $AC$ with the ratio $r_{AC}$.

Q: What are the coordinates of the intersections of the 2 Apollonius circles ? Is there a "good looking formula"?